# How to access variables in sequence of UVM

Tags: uvm

I'm learning UVM and confused by how to access variables of sequence. For example, here is a piece of code for base_sequence which derived from UVM_sequence. Now I want to change value of n_times from top of test,  how can I know the hierarchy of a sequence so that I can use UVM_config_db?

```
class base_sequence extends uvm_sequence;
  ...... 
  my_data  data_obj;
  int unsigned      n_times;
  .......

  virtual task body ();
     ...... 
     repeat (n_times) begin
        start_item (data_obj);
        assert (data_obj.randomize ());
        finish_item (data_obj);
     end
  endtask
  ......
```

endclass

thanks.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660205/i-am-getting-an-error-while-trying-to-pass-the-data-from-scoreboard-to-sequence).

Comment: thank you. I also got another way to set this value. I also put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Matthew Taylor's information. I also find another way to set variables in the sequence. 
[Here is the link for this](https://www.chipverify.com/forum/289-how-to-end-simulation-with-uvm)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access a sequence hierarchically, since sequence is not part of the testbench hierarchy. The solution to change '`n_times`' in the sequence is to either pass down the value till the class where you start the sequence and assign it there. You also can use the config db `get/set` method.

From the test:

```
uvm_config_db#(int)::set(uvm_root::get(),"","n_times", n_times );
```

In the sequence:

```
uvm_config_db#(int)::get(null, "", "n_times", n_times)
```

Comment: The principle behind this answer is right, but I think there are mistakes. For example, you can't call `get_sequencer()` from a test.

Comment: could you please provide an example on how to do this? thanks

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Thanks for pointing out. I replied in haste without checking.